# ng-repeat not working on data set retrieved using resolve property

Tags: angularjs

I try to display all elements in a data set I get from the resolve property.

This :

```
Cours : {{courses}}
```

Displays this :

```
Cours : {"courses":[{"_id":"56cb521b83fcd7c023ee041f","code":"12345","name":"Test3","professor":"MonsieurX","courseContentGrade":1,"courseTeachingGrade":3,"courseAverage":2,"__v":1,"reviews":["56cb54bebd9861f004973dcb"]},{"_id":"56cb57c9e01f4a340988c6c0","code":"123456789","name":"SuperCours","courseContentGrade":7,"courseTeachingGrade":9,"__v":1,"reviews":["56cb5869e01f4a340988c6c1"]},{"_id":"56cb58f7e0f29d54251e328b","code":"123456789","name":"SuperCours","courseContentGrade":7,"courseTeachingGrade":9,"__v":1,"reviews":["56cb592ce0f29d54251e328c"]}]}
```

But this doesn't work :

```
<div ng-repeat="course in courses">
  {{course.name}}
</div>
```

Here is the code from my resolve property :

```
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
        coursePromise: ['courses', function (courses){
            return courses.getCourses();
        }]
    }
```

the getCourses() function from the service courses :

```
o.getCourses = function () {
    return $http.get('/courses').success(function (data){
        angular.copy(data, o.courses);
    });
};
```

I really have no clue where to start. Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

Here is the code in my controller, pretty simple :

```
angular.module('CMT.MainCtrl', []).controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', 'courses', '$location',
function($scope, courses, $location){

  $scope.courses = courses;


    $scope.go = function(){
        $location.path('/cours/reviews')
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scope variable `courses` is an object, not an array.

This object has a property `courses` that contains the array you want

So you could do in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="course in courses.courses">
  {{course.name}}
</div>
```

I think what you really want to do is fix service to return `o.courses`. 
The use of `success` is deprecated and you should get used to using `then()` as part of the promise chain.

```
o.getCourses = function () {
    return $http.get('/courses').then(function (response){
        var data = response.data;
        angular.copy(data.courses, o.courses);
        return o.courses;
    });
};
```

Comment: hi,

I followed your advice and modified the getCourses() function in my service but now I still cannot access courses and {{courses}} doesn't work anymore. I think don't understand your solution. Can you give me some pointers to use it effectively ?

Thank you

Comment: try just returning `data` . I don't know what `o.courses` is. Any errors?

Comment: o is the object I return from my factory service. I already tried returning data but it didn't work :)

Comment: Are you inspecting errors? Have you tried logging things to console to see what they look like?

Comment: yes, I have nothing on the inspector except an app.js 404 that's been there since the beginning without hindering the project at all.

Comment: If I use the console log, it seems courses is composed of only two empy objects of type courses (an object o and the function getCourses)

Comment: that's the whole factory or service.